# Getting Part Documents From Assembly Documents in SolidWorks API

Tags: c#, solidworks

Here is my scenario: I am reading in an Assembly file into Solidworks. From there, when the user is trying to edit a part, I want to get the information on which part file they want to edit.

Is there a way to get all the `PartDoc` information upon importing an `AssemblyDoc` file?
The closest I got to was getting the `Body2` objects from the `AssemblyDoc` using
`GetComponents()` and `GetBodies2()` function described [here](http://help.solidworks.com/2012/English/api/sldworksapi/Insert_MidSurface_in_Component_Example_CSharp.htm). I had hoped that I could somehow grab the `PartDocs` from the bodies but I've found no way out.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GetComponents](http://help.solidworks.com/2012/English/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.IAssemblyDoc~GetComponents.html) return an array of [IComponent2](http://help.solidworks.com/2012/English/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.IComponent2_members.html)s.

For each component you can call [GetModelDoc2](http://help.solidworks.com/2012/English/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.IComponent2~GetModelDoc2.html) method to retrieve corresponding ModelDoc which can be either PartDoc, or AssemblyDoc.